# Mapping out subregions of neighbors in a matrix and calculating center of mass for each sub-region

Tags: c, matlab, math, image-processing, signal-processing

I have been presented with a problem which involves the following:

1. Given an MxN matrix with some values.
2. Given a threshold value T

**Problems**

- Identify sub-regions in the matrix.

A sub-region is a region of cells in the matrix which are considered neighbors and where the cell values in that sub-region are greater than T. Two cells C1 and C2 are considered to be neighbors if they're adjacent. They are also neighbors if they're diagonally adjacent.

- Calculate the "center of mass" for each sub-region, defined to be the average position (x,y) of the cells in the sub-region. Each cell's location is weighted by its value.

**My approach**

1. Search through MxN matrix to qualify cells and add them as nodes to a linked list (their value must be greater than threshold value).
2. Pull a node from the linked list and put it in a "tree". That node will be the parent node. Search through linked list of remaining nodes to find "nearest neighbors" based on definition of what a neighbor is. Each neighbor is placed as in the "tree" as a child node. Now ..for each child node...search through linked list of remaining nodes to find their neighbors. Continue with this until done. The final tree will be a representation of a sub-region.
3. Go to 2 (and create a new tree) if linked list is not empty

After that, calculating the "center of mass" for each tree will be easy.

Does this seem to be the right approach or is there a better, more optimal one.

Hoping for some feedback.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I should probably mention that the matrix is "placed" in a (x,y) coordinate system so that the lower-left corner cell (row M, column 0) corresponds to the (x,y) coordinate (0,0) and the top right corner cell (row 0, column N) corresponds to the (x,y) coordinate (N,M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you could do that with [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html).

Assuming `M` is your matrix and `T` the threshold value:

```
subregions = regionprops(M > T, 'Centroid');
```

Now you have the centroids on `subregions(i).Centroid`, for each subregion `i`.

Comment: Rafael: That's cool -- so thank you for that! However, I'm interested in knowing if my approach sounds right?